# extra argument userinfo in call

Tags: swift, timer, notifications, userinfo

Get the compile error message from xCode with Swift language: "extra argument userinfo in call". the question is how to use userInfo data from timer to argument "userInfo" in notification center.

```
    func onSetAudioWithTrackIndex(CurrentTrackIndex:Int, urlAudio: String){

    ........
    //try to pass currentTrackIndex data to timerfire
    playTimeClock = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.4, target: self, selector: "onSetPlayProgressTime:", userInfo: CurrentTrackIndex, repeats: true)

}

//Timerfire
func onSetPlayProgressTime(timer: NSTimer){

    var currentTime = mediaPlayer.currentPlaybackTime
    var playDuration = mediaPlayer.duration

    var trackIndexDict = ["trackIndex" : timer.userInfo]

    ................

    if currentTime == playDuration{                   
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification, object: self, userInfo: trackIndexDict)
    }


    return
}
```

Comment: Can you check your labels are correct and complete - e.g. what language is this?

Comment: first time to raise question here. updated description and labels. language is swift

Comment: Please *copy/paste* your *real code*. Typos like `MPMoivePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification` or a missing colon in `userInfo ["trackIndex":timer.userInfo]` make your question unclear.

Answer (score 5):

Swift can give you slightly strange compiler errors sometimes, which amount to “there were multiple possible options, none of them worked, so here’s what’s wrong with one of them”.  When the one it complains about is not the one you were trying for, this can be very strange

This is why Swift tells you so often that something is “not a Int8” even though that has nothing to do with what you were trying to do (huh, I was trying to concatenate two strings, what have Int8s got to do with anything? – it’s because one of the possible options for the `+` operator is to work on Int8s so that’s the one it chooses to complain about).

In this case, `postNotificationName` has multiple overloaded versions, one with 1 argument, one with 2, and one with 3 (the one you want).  None of them fit the types you’ve supplied so it’s saying “one of the options is a call with 2 arguments, and you supplied 3, so that won’t work, there’s an extra argument”.

Unfortunately this is really quite confusing and throws you off the scent of what is actually wrong.  Assuming you cut and pasted your actual code, looks like there’s a spelling error in `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification`, and the `userInfo` argument label is missing a colon after it.

(p.s. you don’t need to explicitly put a return at the end of functions that return void, though it doesn’t do any harm)

Comment: Thanks Airspeed Velocity, this pointed me in the right direction. In my case I used a enum type with String rawValues to define different notification names, but forgot to unwrap it to String: NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(Notifications.MyNote1, object: nil, userInfo: ["myKey":myValue]), which gives me the Extra Argument error. After I unwrap the enum option to rawValue like Notifications.MyNote1.rawValue the compilation error disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

In swift 3 , I got this same error. When I was converting the swift 2.2 to swift 3, as the syntax was changed so it throws this error.

Swift 3:

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification), object: self, userInfo: trackIndexDict)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is
that the `userInfo` property of `NSTimer` is an *optional*:

```
var userInfo: AnyObject? { get }
```

so that `trackIndexDict` has the type `[String : AnyObject?]` which is not convertible
to `[NSObject : AnyObject]` as expected by the last parameter of `postNotificationName()`.

With *optional binding* you can "test and unwrap" the property:

```
if currentTime == playDuration {
    if let timerInfo: AnyObject = timer.userInfo {
        let trackIndexDict = ["trackIndex" : timerInfo]

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification,
            object: self,
            userInfo: trackIndexDict)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

thanks, Martin, this(userInfo of **NSTimer** is optional) is root cause. with the below change. this can be fixed

```
if let timerUserInfo: AnyObject = timer.userInfo! {      
      NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification), object: self, userInfo: ["trackIndex":timerUserInfo])
}
```

Comment: The exclamation mark `!` in `if let timerUserInfo: AnyObject = timer.userInfo!` is wrong, and the code should not compile. Apart from that, isn't that exactly what I suggested? (Note that you can "accept" a helpful answer by clicking on the *check mark*. That marks the problem as solved and gives some reputation points to you and to the author of the answer.)