# Extra argument 'userinfo' in call CLLocation

Tags: ios, swift, cllocation, userinfo

The following code gives me an `Extra argument 'userinfo' in call` error. I've looked at the suggestions from [@27620493](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27620493/extra-argument-userinfo-in-call) and [27875005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27875005/swift-extra-argument-in-call-with-scheduledtimerwithtimeinterval)

```
class SOViewController : UIViewController {

var currentLocation : CLLocation!

func setCurrentLocation(currentLocation: CLLocation) {

    if (self.currentLocation == currentLocation) {
        return
    }
    self.currentLocation = currentLocation

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(aName: SOCurrentLocationDidChangeNotification, object: nil, userInfo: ["kSOLocationKey" : currentLocation]))


}
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error considering `currentLocation` is optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify code for that:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(SOCurrentLocationDidChangeNotification, object: nil, userInfo: ["kSOLocationKey" : currentLocation])
})
```